# Checking if a definition has a method, to add (or not) a method call?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

In my Bundle extension I'm adding method calls (dynamically, based on the configuration) to my service definition `my.service`:

```php
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    // ...

    // Get the defintion
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('my.service');

    // Dynamically add method calls to the definition
    foreach($config['options'] as $name => $value) {
        $definition->addMethodCall('set'.ucfirst($name), array($value));
    }

    // ...
}
```

I would like to **not to call `addMethodCall`** if the method does not exist in the definition. Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you only want to add the method calls on your service class if your service class has definitions for those methods

```
$serviceMethods = get_class_methods($definition->getClass());
//loop on your added methods

$method = 'set'.ucfirst($name);
if(in_array($method, $serviceMethods))
{
    $definition->addMethodCall($method, array($value));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you not get the class using..

```
$class = $definition->getclass();
```

And then check if the method exists before adding it..

```
foreach($config['options'] as $name => $value) {
    $method = 'set'.ucfirst($name);

    if (method_exists($class, $method)
    {
        $definition->addMethodCall('set'.ucfirst($name), array($value));
    }
}
```